# Abstract Classes Passing Reference to an object

Tags: class, abstract

I'm working on a small toy problem and I am trying to understand inheritance and object references.

I have 1 abstract class called BakingStrategy

I have 2 sub classes called MakeCookie and MakeCake

```
public abstract BakingStrategy
{
  public int sugar_amt;
  public int_flour_amt;

  public abstract BakeMe();
}
```

Now the sub classes inherits BakingStrategy there's no issue there.

The issue is there is another class called InComingOrders.

The class InComingOrders sends in an order every second.

How do I make an instance of IncomingOrders in my BakingStrategy so I don't have to create 2 instances of InComingOrders in MakeCookie and MakeCake but instead Pass a reference of IncomingOrders to MakeCookie and MakeCake?

I hope I explained what I meant okay.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "InComingOrders sends in an order every second"? Who receives that order? Maybe you're missing another class, something like OrderDispatcher or something with a similar name. That class would handle the orders by creating the appropriate strategy.

Comment: @Overlord you were right there was a missing piece.  Thank you.